# Pandas add column after resample and unstack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe including an `AXLES` column. The `AXLES` column has always one of the following values: `[3, 4, 5, ,6 ,7, 8]`. I run a filter, then change the index, then groupby, then resample, and finally unstack a dataframe, as seen in the code below.

```
resamp = df[(df.GVW > 100) & (df.AXLES.isin([3,4,5,6,7,8]))].set_index('TIMESTAMP').groupby('AXLES').resample('M', how='count').CLASS
dfTemp = resamp.unstack(0)
dfTemp.index = [ts.strftime('%b 20%y') for ts in dfTemp.index]
```

This gives me the following dataframe, which is ok.

```
AXLES         4   5   6   7  8
Jul 2016    191 1582 212 183 6
```

However, here is the problem: due to the `dfWIM.GVW > 100` filtering I applied, all rows with `AXLES` = 3 are filtered out. How can I still keep this dropped column in the final dataframe? I am trying to get the final data frame as follows (missing "3" column with "0" value added to the dataframe):

```
AXLES       3   4    5   6   7  8
Jul 2016    0  191 1582 212 183 6
```

If it is not possible to keep the dropped columns after all the filtering, how can I add any of the `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` columns (if missing) with the value = 0 to the final dataframe?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Without seeing the original dataframe, it's a little hard to answer, but if you're filtering out any values <= 100, why would you expect the column where a value is 0 to stay?

Comment: I have to prepare monthly bar charts using the filtered data. If one of the columns is dropped in some of the months, that messes up my plotting functions, I have to ensure the dataframe size to be constant. I think once all the filtering is done, I have to repopulate dataframe with the missing columns.

Comment: So does my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an answer to the last part of your question, not a full answer:

pythonically find the missing columns:

```
missing = list(set([3,4,5,6,7,8]) - set(df.columns.tolist()))
```

Option 1 (python):

```
for x in missing: df[x] = 0
```

Option 2 (pandas):

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(columns = [missing])).fillna(0)
```